# Where can I find the IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY structure in the headers of a portable executable?

Tags: c#, windows, header, portable-executable

I would like to access the [IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_image_load_config_directory32) of a PE file using C#. I have tried for quite some time now to access this structure via the [GetImageConfigInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-getimageconfiginformation) however all attempts have been [unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101549/getlasterror-returning-13-or-87-how-to-rectify/56108682#56108682).

I would like to know is there another header that points to the IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY structure in a portable executable? The goal here being to just read the module in like I would any other file and then parse the required entries to find this structure.

Are there any other simpler ways of accessing this information from a PE file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to locate the data directories part of the PE optional header. If the Load Config Table is present, it will be the 11th data directory in the "array" of data directories (that is, the data directory entry at index 10).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#optional-header-data-directories-image-only.

Comment: This worked out great. Thank you for the info. I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your answer yet but when I do get it I will make sure it get's an upvote.